Setting up recurrence relations
Here's the question:

A motorway has two lanes going in my direction.
Whenever traffic moves, if I'm in the left lane I switch to the right with probability $0.6$.
If I'm in the right lane I switch back to the
left lane with probability $0.80$, because it's supposed to be faster.
Over the long term, what fraction of the time do I expect to spend in the left lane ?.

What's wrong with this reasoning ?:

Let $\operatorname{P}\left(L\right)$ be the probability of staying in the left lane. $p_{1}$ is the probability of staying on the left given I am currently on the left. $p_{2}$ is the probability of switching to the left given I am currently on the right.
So I get this equation: $\operatorname{P}\left(L\right) = p_{1}/2 + p_{2}/2$ since at the beginning we randomly choose which lane to be in.
Now the eqn for $p_{1}$ is: $p_{1} = 0.4p_{1} + 0.6p_{2}$
Similarly the equation for $p_{2}$ is $p_{2} = 0.8p_{1} + 0.2p_{2}$
But now I get $p_{1} = p_{2} = \operatorname{P}\left(L\right)$ and no numerical answer for $\operatorname{P}\left(L\right)$.

I know how to do it using the steady state Markov Chain Method but what's wrong with my reasoning here ?.
Thanks.

What is $P(L)$? Also, is time discrete or a continuum here?

Do you mean $p_2$ is the probability of switching to the left given that you are on the right? If so, I fail to see why $P(L)=\frac12 p_1+\frac12 p_2$, as you write in $(2)$. Also, why is $p_1=p_2$ in $(5)$?

Your step 2 looks irrelevant in the long term while steps 3 and 4 look wrong. In addition, the notation looks confused.  If $p_L$ is the long-term fraction of time you are in the left lane (the answer to the question) and $p_R=1-p_L$ in the right lane, then $p_L=0.4p_L+0.8p_R$ and $p_R=0.6p_L+0.2p_R$ leading to $p_L=\frac47\approx 0.57$ and $p_R=\frac37\approx 0.43$.

@Henry why are steps 3 and 4 wrong? The intuition behind 3 for example was:
P(staying on the left long term | you're on the left at the moment) = P(stay on the left at the next time step)*P(staying on the left long term | you're on the left at the moment) + P(move to the right) * P(stay on the left long term|you're on the right at the moment)

What happens in the long term does not depend substantially on where you are at the moment - over the long term you will move from one side to the other and back many times.  Instead: P(being on left in long term e.g. at point $n+1$) is P(being on left in long term e.g. at point $n$) * P(continue on left) + P(being on right in long term e.g. at point $n$) * P(move from right to left)

For consistency, we will assume the following discrete-time stochastic process:

At each timestep, $L$ transitions to $R$ with probability $p_{L \to R} = \frac{3}{5}$, and $R$ transitions to $L$ with probability $p_{R \to L} = \frac{4}{5}$.

From this, you obviously have that $p_{L \to L} = 1 - p_{L \to R} = 1 - \frac{3}{5} = \frac{2}{5}$ and $p_{R \to R} = 1 - p_{R \to L} = 1 - \frac{4}{5} = \frac{1}{5}$.
Suppose that in the steady state, a vehicle remains in the left lane a fraction $p_L$ of the timesteps (I think this is what you are trying to represent with $P (L)$.) Similarly, let the fraction of timesteps spent in the right lane be $p_R = 1 - p_L$.
The fraction $p_L$ should be equal to $p_{L \to L}$ times $p_L$ itself plus $p_{R \to L}$ times $p_R = 1 - p_L$. Therefore,
$$p_L = p_{L \to L} p_L + p_{R \to L} (1 - p_L) = \frac{2}{5} p_L + \frac{4}{5} (1 - p_L)$$
$$\implies \frac{7}{5} p_L = \frac{4}{5} \implies p_L = \boxed{\frac{4}{7}}$$
Looking at your solution, steps 3 and 4 have problems. You mentioned that

P(staying on the left long term | you're on the left at the moment) = P(stay on the left at the next time step)*P(staying on the left long term | you're on the left at the moment) + P(move to the right) * P(stay on the left long term|you're on the right at the moment)

This does not make sense. The probability that you are in $L$ at a randomly selected timestep can be conditioned on the preceding timestep: if the preceding timestep is $L$ (which occurs with frequency $p_L$), then the conditional probability of $L$ is the probability of remaining, which is $p_{L \to L}$; if the preceding timestep is $R$ (which occurs with frequency $p_R$), then the conditional probability of $L$ is the probability of switching, which is $p_{R \to L}$. In particular, you should not be considering the situation where you "move to the right".
If you do this, then the two equations that you get from defining both $p_L$ and $p_R$ are identical; i.e., one of them is redundant:
$$\begin{cases}
p_L = \frac{2}{5} p_L + \frac{4}{5} p_R \Longleftrightarrow \frac{3}{5} p_L = \frac{4}{5} p_R \\
p_R = \frac{3}{5} p_L + \frac{1}{5} p_R \Longleftrightarrow \frac{4}{5} p_R = \frac{3}{5} p_L
\end{cases}$$
To solve for the probabilities, you need one additional equation, which of course is given by $1 = p_L + p_R$.

Thanks for the response. I think where I am getting confused is trying to use a similar technique as recursive expectation.
For example a technique similar to this: What is the expected number of tries to get 6
when rolling dice?
$E[x]=1/6∗1+5/6∗(1+E[x])⟹E(x)=6$
Because we are dealing with probabilities is that why we need to condition on the previous timestep?

@Apex345 Excuse my late response; I didn't see your message. This is not a problem about expectation but about strady-state probabilities, so yes, the approach is slightly different. You don't necessarily need to condition on the preceding timestep; you could also condition on the following timestep, for example (and you will get the same result).
